# How can make Garbage Collector real time in android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, real-time

I am working for making Android Platform real time , So there is a need to make GC real time. I had searched a lot of things to making GC real time and found some solution. Please see belo PDF file :

[Please see Page No -7 of this PDF](http://www.utdallas.edu/~cxl137330/courses/spring14/AdvRTS/protected/slides/45.pdf)

in this PDF file they use a ServiceRT calss for making GC realtime . Plase tell me where we can use use this service class and how we can use this ServiceRT class.

Thanks in advance. PLease share your thought .

Regards,
Amit.

Comment: One obvious way to improve performance in general, and get better RT behavior - use Android's native API, abolish garbage collection and use std C++ smart pointers instead.